# Confused about "Locked" policy

Tags: support

I'm confused about policy.  I posted a question and another user used the edit feature to remove part of it he thought should be in a seperate question.  I rolled the change back as I did not agree with the change.  That user then "Locked" my question.

What does it mean for the question to be Locked?  What happens now with it?

Answer (score 3):

You asked multiple questions.

As per Meta StackOverflow, our parent "site policy" site:

- [What do we do with "Multiple question "questions""?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120633/what-do-we-do-with-multiple-question-questions)
- [Multi-Question Questions: How Best to Handle Them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/multi-question-questions-how-best-to-handle-them)

In short, what we did was edit out your second, unrelated question and said "hey, please go ask another question."

As for locked, because you kept rolling back the edit, another moderator locked it for 24 hours. It will expire at that point, and then you can edit your question - **however**, at that point in time, if you continue to roll back the edit, then we will lock it again, and for a longer (perhaps permanent) period of time.

Comment: Well I don't agree that the second question was unrelated, but it looks like as you have a moderator bit the system respects your opinion on this matter more than mine.